# Create a custom collection which can store millions of entries

Tags: java, list, collections, size

I currently have a specific need with Tables/ArrayList/Collections.

Indeed, I have to store up to 15 000 000 (fifteen millions) instances of a custom class into a table/List/Collection.

It seems that the generic collection classes and tables are not able to store this amount of entries. Actually, my need is to be able to handle the table index with a Long.

I made somes searches, and have found many tutorials showing me how to create a custom collection. The problem is the fact that all those examples have the same size limit.

Do you know any way for me to be able to create something like that?

Thank you in advance!

PS: Sorry for my english writing mistakes.

Comment: The value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2.147.483.647 which is obviously greater than 15.000.000. So you do not have to handle the index with a `long` value. The other issue is memory: Needing to handle 15 millions of objects _in-memory_ is a smell. Consider using a database, or - better - consider a redesign.

Comment: You might want to check one of the answers as correct one or comment on why they don't help you ...

Answer (score 0):

A `List` can store up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2^31-1 > 2.10^9` elements.

It is enough to store all your 15 million elements without any customization. You should try.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not the list. As others have mentioned every ArrayList can store this amount of entries (and many more)

If you have issues, then it's about the size of the objects themselfes which you try to store in memory. (And perhaps the creation time of your list.)

If you really need to store them in memory (and there is nothing *fundamental* wrong about that) try to minimize the objects size. Not knowing what your elements consist of I can't help you there.

If you don't really need them in memory then put them in a file, perhaps with fixed line-length so that you can seek (this really is fast!) to the correct position.